# Dell Latitude 5520 microphone and camera stopped working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, microphone, webcam, dell-latitude

On one Dell Latitude 5520 notebook with Windows 10 latest version the Realtek microphone array and the Integrated WebCam stopped working.

Uninstalling, reinstalling drivers, updating everything including BIOS does not work.
Checking also privacy etc. with no avail. No common tips that can be found by Google work.

F12 - diagnostics - shows no error.

In compmgmt.msc - drivers I can see Realtek microphone array but zero sound comes from it.
I do not see Integrated WebCam - there is no hardware like that.

Is it 100% hardware failure or any workaround available?

Comment: Download the Dell Hardware Diagnostics App and run that to see if that tells you anything different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a hardware failure.
You can check the inside of the notebook whether the cable connecting the camera and the mic to the mainboard is plugged properly.